# Office ribbon with Metro UI for WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, ribbon

I am trying to setup an Metro UI styled application, which includes MAHAPPS.METRO, AvalonDock (Metro style) and MS Ribbon component. Unfortunatelly, there is not much information about Ribbon UI styling especially for Metro UI. So basically my questions are... how to style MS Ribbon according to Metro UI on Win7?

Comment: Do you need to use Microsoft WPF Ribbon control, or any other control? I found this link after googling for a while: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23199/WPF-C-Ribbon-Control-Library and, a proprietary one from Telerik: http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/ribbonview.aspx. Hope this will help someone.

Comment: I don't need to use the specifically the above control but it is free. I did found some commercial alternatives however current project does not justify the additional cost.

Answer (score 2):

The [Fluent Ribbon](https://github.com/fluentribbon/Fluent.Ribbon) has a Metro style. The control is open source, so you can make any changes to the control, or the styles as you see fit. I am trying it. It is currently the best open source option I have found.

Comment: I've been using the metro style for the fluent ribbon (https://fluent.codeplex.com/) which is also available as a nuget package and it's been working pretty well.